# Typescript error (Property 'submitter' does not exist on type 'Event') when trying to grab value |REACT|

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

I have a React form that has two submit buttons that hit two different endpoints with Axios.

When I try to grab the form submitter's value (which endpoint to hit), I get the following error when using React with TS.

**Property 'submitter' does not exist on type 'Event'**

My code is as follows:

```
  async function handleSubmit(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    const submitter = e.nativeEvent.submitter.value;

    e.preventDefault();
    checkedBox.length > 0 &&
      (await axios
        .post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE}/update${submitter}tasks`,
          checkedBox
        )
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            setForceUpdate((current) => (current += 1));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }));
  }
```

If I change the function type to (e: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) another error pops up on the onSubmit attribute.

```
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

The error is:

***Type '(e: BaseSyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement, any, any>) => Promise' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
Type 'FormEvent' is not assignable to type 'BaseSyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement, any, any>'.
Types of property 'nativeEvent' are incompatible.
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLFormElement': acceptCharset, action, autocomplete, elements, and 294 more.ts(2322)***

Comment: Is this function the submit method of a form ?

Comment: It is, I'm using two submit buttons that will route to two different endpoints using Axios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `SyntheticEvent` and `SubmitEvent`

```js
const handleSubmit = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement, SubmitEvent>) => {}
```

**Explanation**

When we use `FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` it expands to:

```js
FormEvent<T = Element>
  SyntheticEvent<T = Element, E = Event>  // notice it hardcodes Event
    BaseSyntheticEvent<E, EventTarget & T, EventTarget> // also hardcodes EventTarget
      target: EventTarget // hardcoded
      nativeEvent: Event  // hardcoded
      currentTarget: HTMLFormElement & EventTarget
```

So instead of using `FormEvent` use `SyntheticEvent` that results in:

```js
SyntheticEvent<T = HTMLFormElement, E = SubmitEvent>
  BaseSyntheticEvent<E, EventTarget & T, EventTarget>
    target: HTMLFormElement // 
    nativeEvent: SubmitEvent  // 
    currentTarget: HTMLFormElement & EventTarget
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late to the party, but this worked for me in TypeScript:

```
  const handleSubmit = (event: SyntheticEvent) => {
    const eventSubmitter = (event.nativeEvent as SubmitEvent).submitter;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a form:

Transform this

```
async function handleSubmit(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    const submitter = e.nativeEvent.submitter.value;
}
```

To this

```
async function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
    const submitter = e.nativeEvent.submitter.value;
}
```

Additionally you'll probably need to do: `e.nativeEvent?.submitter.value`

Comment: Same error, Property 'submitter' does not exist on type 'Event'.

Comment: Add your form code and more context

Comment: I've added all the function code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the form element since it is useless with axios anyways & turned all buttons into normal buttons with onClicks that trigger the handleSubmit function.

I have it as follows:

```
  async function handleSubmit(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    const submitter = (e.target as HTMLButtonElement).value;
    checkedBox.length > 0 &&
      (await axios
        .post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE}/update${submitter}tasks`,
          checkedBox
        )
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            setForceUpdate((current) => (current += 1));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }));
  }
```

And the buttons as follows:

```
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  name="submit"
                  value="delete"
                  variant="outline-info"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                  size="lg"
                  className="text-center font-main-color"
                > Button </Button>
```